# XElement.Elements(XName name) doesn't return a name that exists in XElement.Elements()

Tags: linq-to-xml, xelement

As you can see, the `schema.Elements` returns three elements one of whom is an EntityContainer element.
But when I try to search thru the Elements overload specifying the "EntityContainer" (`schema.<EntityContainer>`) it doesn't retrieve anything.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer found.

It didn't return anything since the `EntityContainer` element in the edmx file belongs to an imported namespace I forgot to import in my file.

Adding this line solved everything:

```
Imports <xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2009/02/edm/ssdl">
```